# Terminate a telnet session then start another?

Tags: batch-file, vbscript, cmd, telnet

I'm writing a script that loops through a large list of IP addresses, telnets each one, sends login info, then sends the commands to quit. It then checks the logfile for a certain string, and if the string is contained it outputs "it's a UPS!" and "Not a UPS" if the string is not contained. As of right now, the script performs beautifully execpt for one minor error, i cannot get the telnet session to return to the command prompt for the next iteration.  If i push the enter key(or any key) after the telnet session disconnects, the script moves on to the next iteration, but I can't seem to get the script to send that keystroke automatically.  Here is the code:

The scripts entry point:

```
@echo off
FOR %%i IN (10.40.9.131 10.40.1.205) DO logtest.bat %%i
```

logtest.bat:

```
@echo off

cscript SendKeys.vbs

telnet %1 -f diditwork.txt


find /c "User" diditwork.txt
if errorlevel 1 goto notfound
echo Tis a UPS
goto done
:notfound
echo not a ups
goto done
:done
```

SendKeys.vbs:

```
set OBJECT=WScript.CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
WScript.sleep 100 
OBJECT.SendKeys "apc{ENTER}" 
WScript.sleep 50 
OBJECT.SendKeys "apc{ENTER}"
WScript.sleep 50  
OBJECT.SendKeys "4{ENTER}"
WScript.sleep 50 
OBJECT.SendKeys "quit{ENTER}"
WScript.sleep 50

OBJECT.SendKeys "{ENTER}"
WScript.sleep 50
```

Answer (score 0):

Try working with telnet **`open`** and **`close`** commands like

```
telnet

for each address
  open x.x.x.x
  do stuff
  close

quit
```

Answer (score 0):

I'd recommend using [PuTTY](http://www.chiark.greenend.org.uk/~sgtatham/putty/) (or, more specifically, [plink](http://tartarus.org/~simon/putty-snapshots/htmldoc/Chapter7.html#plink-usage)) if you want to batch-run telnet scripts.

Answer (score 0):

Google on this, for a scriptable telnet tool for windows.

Telnet Scripting Tool v.1.0
by Albert Yale ay@aci.qc.ca http://ay.home.ml.org/

Answer (score 0):

I found a way to collect the PID of each TELNET window I open using ProcessID. I can then reference the specific window using that TELNET session ID and capture the focus, so when I use SendKeys to input commands it inputs them to the correct window (most of the time). My situation requires multiple TELNET windows open simultaneously.

(Found your post looking for a way to move/resize the window, but I thought I'd share anyway :)

When I activate the window, I start it like this:

```
Dim Shell, Network
Dim telnet_session01
Dim telnet_session02
Set Shell = WScript.CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
Set Network = WScript.CreateObject("WScript.Network")

Set telnet_session01 = Shell.Exec("""C:\Program Files\Winodws\telnet.exe"" HOST_NAME")
WScript.Sleep 2000
Shell.AppActivate telnet_session01.ProcessID
```

Then I have a sub to call that ProcessID and pass the string:

```
DelayedSendKeysWithFocus telnet_session01, "username"
DelayedSendKeysWithFocus telnet_session01, "password"

Sub DelayedSendKeysWithFocus(procid, str) 
'#! I have not observed consistent behavior while including the Process ID 
'#!  with this SUB - the focus is not always retrained on the window in 
'#!  question before each SendKeys.
  WScript.Sleep 100
  Shell.AppActivate procid
  Shell.SendKeys str
End Sub
```

HTH

Robert